# Make AWS serverless function unique by method/verb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, http-verbs

I got some CRUD operations for my user. I want my URI to be /user/{id} and make the VERB decide what method to use, eg. post and put.
In my cloudformation template file my resources looks like this:

```
    "UpdateUser" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "AWSServerless::AWSServerless.UserFunctions::UpdateUserAsync",
    "Runtime": "dotnetcore1.0",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "Description": "Function to update a user",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
    "Events": {
      "PutResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/user/{id}",
          "Method": "PUT"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},

"GetUser" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "AWSServerless::AWSServerless.UserFunctions::GetUserAsync",
    "Runtime": "dotnetcore1.0",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "Description": "Function to get a single user",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
    "Events": {
      "PutResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/user/{Id}",
          "Method": "GET"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That will give me this error: "Unable to create resource at path '/user/{id}': A sibling ({Id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed".

Is it possible to make them unique by the Method/Verb? Or what solution is best..? To have /user/ as my path and send my id in the object, use a querystring or make the path to something like this "/user/update/{id}" "/user/get/{id}"?

Comment: Are you adding multiple events inside the same `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource, or are these separate `AWS::Serverless::Function` resources?

Comment: @tkwargs They are separated. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this example](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_backend/template.yaml), looks there are a few problems in your template:

- Make sure your path params are the same. You are using `{id}` and `{Id}`. It's looking like path params are case sensitive, so you might want to use only `{id}` in both functions.
- For your `GetUser` function, use the `GetResource` event instead of `PutResource`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped to change {Id} to {id}

Comment: the link is broken, unfortunately.